# How to run Watch App in XCode

Tags: ios, objective-c, watchkit, apple-watch

I created a watch app, following [Apple's guide lines](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/WatchKitProgrammingGuide/ConfiguringYourXcodeProject.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014969-CH2-SW1), but not sure how to run it in the simulator.

When I select the Watch App scheme and run it, the iPhone simulator appears, and I can see WatchKit extension running, dumbing some logs

```
2014-11-19 13:28:56.991 WatchApp WatchKit Extension[61833:6371439] <WatchApp_WatchKit_Extension.InterfaceController: 0x7b652010> init
2014-11-19 13:28:56.992 WatchApp WatchKit Extension[61833:6371439] <WatchApp_WatchKit_Extension.InterfaceController: 0x7b652010> will activate
```

But nothing happens on the simulator's screen.

Comment: In the Simulator, select Hardware -> External Display -> Apple Watch

Comment: @Acey you should put it as answer.

Comment: @Acey can you make it an answer?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What you run your WatchKit extension, you need to go to Hardware > External Displays and select an Apple Watch (there are two sizes, either works).

[image]

After this, you can make changes to your code in Xcode and run it, and the changes will be reflected in the WatchKit simulator without you having to mess with enabling the simulator again.

Comment: Yes, Xcode 6.2 Beta 1 does not trigger the activation of the external display.  Please do it manually for now.

Answer (score 3):

If your Watch simulator screen appears, but is black, then that means you have not run the correct target from Xcode. Go back to Xcode and select the "xxx Watch App" target, then run the simulator again. Your external display should now show the Watch App.

[image]